# Asterisk is character 42

Tags: ascii

Just realized asterisk (`*`) is character 42 (`0x2A`, `052`).

Is this related to the significance of the number 42 in *Hitchhiker's guide to the galaxy*? Considering also how asterisk is traditionally associated to a star<sup>1, 2, 3</sup>.

<sub>1: A "star diagram" will often be exemplified with a diagram vaguely resembling a five or six edges asterisk.</sub>

<sub>2: The search algorithm A<sup>*</sup> is commonly called "*A star*", will be found in code references as `astar`.</sub>

<sub>3: Everybody uses an asterisk to represent Kleene's *star* operator.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

There is a long story to the  asterisk `(*)` being `ASCII 42` and is used as:

1. Its a Wild Card
2. There are 42 dots on a pair of dice
3. The sentence "the meaning of life, the universe, and everything" has 42 letters/symbols

and so on...

Anyways, He explains this now culturally entrenched "Answer to The Great Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything" as just a number he came up with while sitting in his garden. And that's just fine with me. The number is unimportant, it's the effect of the joke that matters.